# How should I validate my inputs in the backend?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

My web app will receive a lot of user-generated content. I want to improve basic security by validating inputs that users generate. My backend is running Node+Express.

How should I implement input validation?

1. With assert?
   Coming from Python, I started writing assert statements:
   assert(title.length > 0)
2. With express-validator?
   Then I discovered that there are form validation libraries, such as express-validator. This seemed like the 'right' way of doing it. But compared to simple assertion statements, it also seemed actually like I would double or triple the number of lines of code I need to write.
3. With TypeScript?
   Then I realised that perhaps I could just write some of my Node code in TypeScript, and it would do all the validation for me.
4. ?

Which approach should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is sanitize the user input to prevent XSS.
There are many NPM packages for that, [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) does a great job.

The most basic way to validate the input is to use if statements, for example:

```js
app.post("/user", (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !validator.isEmail(email)) {
        return res.status(400).send("Invalid email");
    } else if (!password || password.length < 8) {
        return res.status(400).send("Invalid password");
    }
    // Do stuff
    return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Validation libraries are pretty useful, in the example above I used the `isEmail` function from `validator`.

Note that TypeScript does **not** do any runtime validation, it performs type-checking during compile time and then compiles the whole TypeScript code into JavaScript, stripping away all the types.

Which means that, for example, even if a field you specified as a string in TypeScript turns out to be a number during runtime, JavaScript won't throw any error, so it's really important that you make sure that every input field is validated.

Validating each input in each request could become quite repetitive and ugly to look at, but thankfully you can implement [Express middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) that you can easily add to the requests that need them.

Comment: Would using assert statements be a wrong way to go about this as well?